# How do I get to the new "cow rift" in Reaper of Souls?

Tags: diablo-iii

There have been reports of a new "cow level" that seems to only be accessible via  Nephalem Rifts:

Are the Rifts fixed in terms of location (act/area)? Are Rifts the only way to get there?

Comment: "There is no cow level" -- Official statement from Blizzard, and they never lie =P

Comment: Even better: "The cow level is a lie"

Comment: Not sure about cow levels, but I did encounter some unicorns in a rift last night. They dropped cupcakes :)

Comment: @z- "There is no cow level" is clearly better because it's the original. It's even being used as a cheat code in StarCraft. Your version also references the inverse situation where something is supposed to be there, but really isn't (while here, it's officially not there, but really is).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cow level is a random rift level. Similar to "development hell" crypt in act 1. You have a random chance of having a rift level spawn only cows, killer bears, or have 25 treasure goblins all huddled together. There are many different rifts that offer a lot of different enemies. And it's all random.

Comment: Yeah, I've encountered one with a whole group of treasure goblins in. It was chaos. Annoyingly most of them got away :(

Comment: I was one of the bears rifts the other day

Answer (score 1):

You get there with a lot of luck :) Roughly 1 in 1000 rifts will be the "cow level".

But what is it?

The cow level has the same name as any other rift, but is rather different. You will enter into a rift similar to the area in an Act 1 crypt. It will be full of cows, "moo".

After a very short hallway you will enter the same area as the Jar of Souls event except the goal will be to kill as many enemies as possible during the timer. Once the timer ends, the Cow Princess, *Heir to the Herd*, will spawn and you kill her.

Once she is done, you progress through the rift as normal, still full of cows. There are technically 10 levels to this rift, although you will complete the progress bar before the end presumably. Once the timer is up, the Lord of Bells appears as the rift guardian. He is part of an achievement.

[image]

Good luck! There are no factors aside from randomness that lead to the cow level.

Answer (score -2):

I believe, like all rifts, it is simply a random chance to get this when you open a rift. Blizzard is talking about making "tiered rifts". It's possible that they will make going into a higher-tiered rift might give a better chance to roll into special rifts like the cow level, but that's only my speculation.