# What is the likelihood to enter a "cow rift"?

Tags: diablo-iii

Note that I'm not asking about the hidden cow level.

[This type of rift](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161962/how-do-i-get-to-the-new-cow-level-in-reaper-of-souls) appears to have been introduced in the Reaper of Souls expansion. I happen to have entered one after opening my third (!) nephalem rift (a new start on the PS4 version, 'Eternal Collection').

Some others have estimated that the chance is about one in a thousand (including [an answer on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/184844/148510)). I wonder if the odds have been adjusted in the subsequent patches.

Comment: I've now also seen a rift floor with Whimsyshire enemies, after completing at most 20 standard rifts in total. Perhaps new players have a higher chance to encounter less common events.  The PlayStation-exclusive "Last of Us" floor has appeared twice.